# @KafkaListener : behavior and tracking processing of events

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

We are using spring-kafka 2.3.0 in our app . Have observed some processing glitches in the scenarios below with

```java
@Service
@EnableScheduling
public class KafkaService {

    public void sendToKafkaProducer(String data) {
    kafkaTemplate.send(configuration.getProducer().getTopicName(), data);
    }
    
    @KafkaListener(id = "consumer_grpA_id", 
    topics = "#{__listener.getEnvironmentConfiguration().getConsumer().getTopicName()}", groupId = "consumer_grpA", autoStartup = "false")
    public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, String> data) throws Exception {
        passA(data);
    }

    private void passB(String message) {
        //counter to keep track of retry attempts
        if (counter.containsKey(message.getEventID())) {
            //RETRY_COUNT = 5
            if (counter.get(message.getEventID()) < RETRY_COUNT) {
                retryAgain(message);
            }
        } else {
            firstRetryPass(message);
        }
    }

    private void retryAgain(String message) {
        counter.put(message.getEventID(), counter.get(message.getEventID()) + 1);
        try {
            registry.stop(); //pause the listener
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void firstRetryPass(String message) {
        // First Time Entry for count and time
        counter.put(message.getEventID(), 1);
        try {
            registry.stop();//pause the listener    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void passA(String message) {
            try {
                passToTarget(message); //Call target processor
                LOGGER.info("Message Processed Successfully to the target");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                targetUnavailable= true;
                passB(message);
            }
    }
    
    private void passToTarget(String message){
        //processor logic, if the target is not available, retry after 15 mins, call passB func
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/15 * 1/1 * ?")
    public void scheduledMethod() {
        try {
            if (targetUnavailable) {
                registry.start();
                firstTimeStart = false;
            }
            LOGGER.info(">>>Scheduler Running ?>>>" + registry.isRunning());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

1. On receipt of the first message after a gap in processing, the consumer doesn't pick up the first message. The subsequent messages are processed.
2. As we don't have the direct access to Kafka topics, we aren't able to identify the process that didn't get picked up from consumer.
3. How do we track those events that arenot picked up  and why is it so.?
4. We also configured a scheduler whose job is to keep the registry for Kafka running . So is this scheduler required when we already have a listener configured ?
5. What is the mem and CPU utilization metrics if we keep the listener running. That was one of the reason we used the Kafka registry to stop the listener explicitly whenever the target is down. So need to validate if this approach is sustainable. My hunch is this is against the basic working of Listener, as it's main job is to continue listening for new events irrespective of target status
   ******Edited*******

Comment: You need to show your configuration and code. There is no inherent reason that records will be skipped, it must be mis-configuration or some other problem. It's not clear what you mean by `a scheduler whose job is to keep the registry for Kafka running`; there is no need for such a thing. Stopping and starting the listener is a perfectly valid use case, if you only want to receive events at certain times during the day.

Comment: @GaryRussell - Thanks for the response. The use-case here is, the messages will be retried for 3-4 times with periodic intervals(15 min schedule ->the scheduler will wake up the consumer listener). But what I am trying to validate is how consumer ensures it needs to pick up a particular message for 'n' retires ? Does the consumer reads the message in round-robin ?The partition might have received new messages as well and consumer would have picked the new messages right ? So how the earlier messages will get processed ? have updated the draft code-base for reference. Thanks

Comment: Was this issue resolved, I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

1. You shouldn't stop the registry on the listener thread unless you use `stop(Runnable)` - otherwise there will be a deadlock and a delay since the container waits for the listener to exit.
2. Stopping the container (via the registry) won't actually take effect until any remaining records fetched by the last poll have been processed (unless you set `max.poll.records=1`.
3. When the listener exits normally, the record's offset will be committed so that record will not be redelivered on the next start.

You can use the `ContainerStoppingErrorHandler` for this use case. See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.1/reference/html/#container-stopping-error-handlers).

Throw an exception and the error handler will stop the container for you.

But that will stop the container on the first try.

If you want retries, use a [`SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.1/reference/html/#seek-to-current) and call the `ContainerStoppingErrorHandler` from the recoverer after retries are exhausted.